# Multiplying Matrix by itself in Java

Tags: java, matrix-multiplication

I have a problem multiplying a matrix. My code looks like this and should multiply the matrix by itself but it isn't working and I have no idea why.

```
class Matrix {
    // Constructor: create a matrix with only zeroes.
    public Matrix(int numRows, int numColumns) {
        this.values = new double[numRows][numColumns];
        this.numRows = numRows;
        this.numColumns = numColumns;
    }

    public int getNumRows() {
        return this.numRows;
    } 

    public int getNumColumns() {
        return this.numColumns;
    }

    public double getValue(int row, int column) {
        return this.values[row][column];
    } 

    public void setValue(int row, int column, double value) {
        this.values[row][column] = value;
    }

    public Matrix multiply(Matrix b) {
        // to be implemented

        int [][] result = new int[Matrix b.length][Matrix b[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix b.length; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < Matrix b[0].length; j++) { 
                for (int k = 0; k < Matrix b[0].length; k++) { 
                    result[i][j] += Matrix b[i][k] * Matrix b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}

public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.numColumns; j++) {
            System.out.print(this.values[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
} 

private double[][] values;
private int numRows;
private int numColumns;

}
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: What errors are you getting? What's not working? What have you tried?

Comment: Please, don't spam tag your questions and format your code so it's easy to read. It's not that hard and any editor does it automagically.

Comment: To be able [multiply a matrix by itself](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/powers-of-a-matrix), it will have to be a square matrix. That gives you also an opportunity to provide better exception handling, knowing that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your `public Matrix multiply(Matrix b)` method should return an object of `Matrix` type, but you do a `return result;`, with result being an array : `int [][] result = new int[Matrix b.length][Matrix b[0].length];`

So your code cannot compile.

You have to construct a `Matrix` object from this `int[][]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Matrix multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b) {
    Matrix m = new Matrix(a.getNumRows(), b.getNumColumns());
    for (int i = 0; i < m.getNumRows(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b.getNumColumns(); j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < a.getNumRows(); k++)
                m.setValue(i, j, a.getValue(i, k) * b.getValue(k, j));
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks like it is working now :)